# Where did I visit?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

My name is Ian, you could say I'm central to the solution. While the answer is where I went on my last vacation, I love to talk about my work... My entire start of the week was spent bombarding atoms with radiation! Towards the end of this week I've spent a lot of time with uncharged selenium. If you've followed along so far you only need to start at the beginning of a common list for the last character!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Pretty sure the anwer is the 'Ionian sea'

> Ian is central to this answer

> The Ionian Sea is a nice holiday destination

> Ions are created when atoms are bombarded by radiation

> Se is the abbreviation for Selenium in the periodic table,

> A is the beginning of the alphabet, a well known list